# Apache Karaf Bundle symbolic name and version are not unique

Tags: maven, deployment, bundle, apache-karaf

I am trying to deploy my OSGi bundle into Karaf. While deploying the bundle using `bundle:install` command, getting below error message:

```
Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Bundle symbolic name and version are not unique: servicebus:5.2.1.SNAPSHOT
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.createRevision(BundleImpl.java:1305)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.4.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.<init>(BundleImpl.java:112)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.4.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.installBundle(Felix.java:2907)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.4.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleContextImpl.installBundle(BundleContextImpl.java:165)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.4.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.karaf.bundle.command.Install.execute(Install.java:77)[63:org.apache.karaf.bundle.core:4.0.0.M2]
    ... 11 more
```

Following are the properties defined in `pom.xml`:

```
<groupId>com.google.process</groupId>
<artifactId>processCheck</artifactId>
<packaging>bundle</packaging>
<version>5.2.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

I defined bundle symbolic name as `servicebus`:

```
<Bundle-SymbolicName>servicebus</Bundle-SymbolicName>
```

Could you please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Probably it is already installed in Karaf's cache. Try to delete the `$karaf.home/data` folder and install it again.

Answer (score 0):

Try to find out if it's already installed by

```
la | grep -i "servicebus"
```

if it's already installed just issue a

```
bundle:update <id>
```

where the id is the id found with the first command. 
If no bundle can be found, do as Jorge Martinez already stated. 
Delete the data folder. 
You might as well do this with a shell command (if you're not using windows ;) )

```
system:shutdown -r -cc
```

where -cc stands for clean cache directory, if you want to make sure the complete data folder is purged (including log)

```
system:shutdown -r -ca
```